# how to plot multiple lines between two points representing in two columns of a data frame using ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

hello everyone  I have the following data frame:

Here is my df:

```
C1 <- c(-1.363953,4.265514,5.609484,7.524796,2.562210,7.214769, 4.667354,4.950837,4.134733,7.540626)
C2 <- c(-1.541836,4.248582,5.557042,7.475255,2.424585,7.125046,4.524404  4.890195,3.945435,7.488123)

Name <- paste(letters[1:10])
df <- data.frame(Name = paste(letters[1:10]), C1, C2)


Name        C1        C2.     
 a      -1.363953   -1.541836  
 b       4.265514    4.248582  
 c       5.609484    5.557042  
 d       7.524796    7.475255  
 e       2.562210    2.424585  
 f       7.214769    7.125046  
 g       4.667354    4.524404  
 h       4.950837    4.890195  
 i       4.134733    3.945435  
 j       7.540626    7.488123
```

How can I draw a line between two values of column c1 and c2 at each row. I would like to have 10 lines which connect C1 entry at each row to C2 entry.

For example I want to have line between -1.363953 and  -1.541836?

Do you have any idea how can I do this using ggplots in r? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df = melt(df)

ggplot(df,aes(x=variable,y=value,group=Name,colour=Name)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Actually I have multiple of these plots and I want to plot the all at once in one page. I am using plot_grid(). this function plot all of them in one view but it looses the ggplot theme and background. Do you know how can I plot them all together without any changes in original plots?